# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when use JFoenix with javafxports 8.60.8 - How to use JFoenix with JavaFXPorts?

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon-mobile

This is error from logcat when I am using JFoenix with JavaFXPorts:

```
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'javafx.scene.layout.Background com.jfoenix.skins.JFXButtonSkin.lambda$new$251(com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton)' was expected to be of type direct but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'com.jfoenix.skins.JFXButtonSkin' appears in /data/app/sk.jfoenixtestapplication-1/base.apk)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXButtonSkin.access$lambda$3(JFXButtonSkin.java)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXButtonSkin$$Lambda$4.call(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.beans.binding.Bindings$6.computeValue(Bindings.java:338)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.get(ObjectBinding.java:153)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:53)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.addListener(ObjectBinding.java:72)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.bind(ObjectPropertyBase.java:173)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.bind(StyleableObjectProperty.java:75)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXButtonSkin.<init>(JFXButtonSkin.java:108)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton.createDefaultSkin(JFXButton.java:91)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:858)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2396)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:348)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.access$lambda$3(Toolkit.java)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:347)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:374)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:503)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$387(QuantumToolkit.java:321)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.access$lambda$2(QuantumToolkit.java)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
10-31 11:01:10.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5873):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am using JavaFXPorts 8.60.8 and Gluon mobile plugin in NetBeans.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Post your build.gradle in the first place. As a lucky guess, are you using the JFoenix dependency that includes retrolambda? The new version of the plugin will try to apply it again and that will fail. Use `compileNoRetrolambda` if this is the case.

Comment: `dependencies {
    //...
    compileNoRetrolambda files('lib/jfoenix-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-retrolambda.jar')
}` - This helped me.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as a full answer, so it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new jfxmobile plugin 1.1.0+ includes some [changes](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.0/#_migration_guide_to_gluon_mobile_4) related on how Retrolambda is applied to the project *and* to the dependencies.

Before 1.1.0, each dependency should be free of lambda expressions, as the retrolambda plugin wasn't able to act on them.

Since 1.1.0+, the plugin applies retrolambda to third party dependencies as well.

In case these dependencies were using the retrolambda plugin, we can't apply it twice, at this will fail with the exception posted by the OP.

To avoid this issue, we can use `compileNoRetrolambda` or `runtimeNoRetrolambda`, instead of the usual `compile` or `runtime`, that we'll use only on dependencies without retrolambda:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.0'
    compileNoRetrolambda 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
}
```